# onEditingComplete is not called after unfocus

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField like this. The additional code is necessary to show that in different situations, I do various focus manipulation.

```
  final node = FocusScope.of(context);
  Function cleanInput = () => {controller.text = controller.text.trim()};
  Function onEditingComplete;
  Function onSubmitted
  TextInputAction textInputAction;
  if (!isLast) {
    onEditingComplete = () => {
          cleanInput(),
          node.nextFocus(),
        };
    onSubmitted = (_) => {cleanInput()};
    textInputAction = TextInputAction.next;
  } else {
    onEditingComplete = () => {
          cleanInput(),
        };
    onSubmitted = (_) => {
          cleanInput(),
          node.unfocus(),
        };
    textInputAction = TextInputAction.done;
  }
  Widget textInput = TextField(
      textInputAction: textInputAction,
      controller: controller,
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
      keyboardType: textInputType,
      ));
```

As you can see, I have functions I want to run `onEditingComplete`. However, this only gets called when I press the `Next` or `Done` buttons on my keyboard (or the Enter key in an emulator). If I change focus by tapping on a different field, this function does not get called.

I have tried using a `Focus` or `FocusNode` to help with this, but when I do so, the `onEditingComplete` function itself no longer works.

How can I get the desired effect here while everything plays nicely together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Focus widget

Wrapping fields in a `Focus` widget might do the trick.

The `Focus` widget will capture focus loss events for children.  With its `onFocusChange` argument you can call arbitrary functions.

Meanwhile, the `onEditingComplete` argument of TextField is unaffected and will still be called on the software keyboard "Next/Done" keypress.

This should handle field focus loss for both "Next/Done" keypress and user tapping on another field.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldFocusPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              // ↓ Add this wrapper
              Focus(
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name'
                  ),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  // ↓ Handle focus change on Next / Done soft keyboard keys
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    print('Name editing complete');
                    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                  },
                ),
                canRequestFocus: false,
                // ↓ Focus widget handler e.g. user taps elsewhere
                onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                  hasFocus ? print('Name GAINED focus') : print('Name LOST focus');
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password'
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Bingo, this did the trick! For future readers, to get the correct effect, I made sure not to call any node focus changing functions in onFocusChange, like this: `Function onFocusChange = (hasFocus) => {hasFocus ? null : cleanInput()};`. You only need those calls in onEditingComplete, like you can see in my original post. As you can see, I only call the function to clean the input here, and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Oh also, I had to use canRequestFocus: false, otherwise the focus node interferes with changing focus in onEditingComplete. This is very important! Could you update your answer Baker to include this?

Comment: @DanielPorteous added the `canRequestfocus:false` for you

Answer (score 1):

Please add a focus node to your textfield and add a listener to your focus node to trigger when it unfocuses

```
   final node = FocusScope.of(context);
   node.addListener(_handleFocusChange);


  void _handleFocusChange() {
    if (node.hasFocus != _focused) {
      setState(() {
        _focused = node.hasFocus;
      });
    }
  }

    Widget textInput = TextField(
      //you missed this line of code
      focusNode: node,
      textInputAction: textInputAction,
      controller: controller,
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
      keyboardType: textInputType,
      ));
```

And also you can validete automatically by adding autoValidate to your code like below:

```
Widget textInput = TextField(
 //add this line of code to auto validate
  autoValidate: true,
  textInputAction: textInputAction,
  controller: controller,
  onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
  onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
  keyboardType: textInputType,
  ));
```

Comment: The first code block does not work, I get this error: `Tried to make a child into a parent of itself`.

As for the second part: There is no `autovalidate` argument to `TextField`. I notice that if I wrap the `TextField` in a `Form`, I can use `autovalidate` (or better, the non deprecated `autovalidateMode`),  but that doesn't actually solve my problem.

Comment: ```Tried to make a child into a parent of itself```
I think this is a hierarchy problem, this block of code should work. Can you please provide the full code of this Widget/Page?

Comment: The given code is all there is. The next step from here is just to return the widget. I then use this function to create n instances of this widget in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
FocusNode _node;
bool _focused = false;

@override
void initState() {
      super.initState();
       _node.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
    }

  void _handleFocusChange() {
        if (_node.hasFocus != _focused) {
          setState(() {
           _focused = _node.hasFocus;
        });
      }
      }
  @override
   void dispose() {
     _node.removeListener(_handleFocusChange);
    _node.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }

    TextFormField(
focusNode: _node)
```

Comment: If I set a focus node on my field, my other functions such as onEditingComplete don't work, it does not switch focus to the next element.