# How can i change TextField on hover in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

Hi i'm trying to change the background color of my TextField Widget in flutter when the user focus on it. But it kinda seems there is no way to do it. If anybody has any idea please let me know ^^.

Here's the Widget itself:

```
TextField(    
                          
                          controller: emailController,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, height: 0.8),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusColor: AppColors.inputBackgroundDarkFocus,
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(color)),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xff25282C),
                            hintText: 'Email',
                            hintStyle:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Thks <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter-Web: Mouse hover -> Change cursor to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211844/flutter-web-mouse-hover-change-cursor-to-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

Hover & focus are two different things, so this might not answer your question, but the below can change field color "on focus" (the cursor is in the field).

If you're implementing purely for Flutter web and you want to handle "hover" you could do the below with a `MouseRegion` wrapper instead of `Focus`.  [Info on MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html).

---

By wrapping a form field in a `Focus` widget, you can listen/capture focus changes on that field using the `onFocusChange` constructor argument (of `Focus`).

It takes a `Function(bool)`.

Here's an example of an `onFocusChange` handler function:

```
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
      print('Name GAINED focus');
      setState(() {
        bgColor = Colors.purple.withOpacity(.2);
      });
    }
    else {
      print('Name LOST focus');

      setState(() {
        bgColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  },
```

If you wrap your field in a `Container`, you can give the Container a color and change that color using a `Focus` widget described above.

Here's a full page example (stolen from [another answer of mine on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65767705/2301224)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldFocusPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldFocusPageState createState() => _TextFieldFocusPageState();
}

class _TextFieldFocusPageState extends State<TextFieldFocusPage> {
  Color bgColor = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              // ↓ Add this wrapper
              Focus(
                child: Container(
                  color: bgColor,
                  child: TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Name'
                    ),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    // ↓ Handle focus change via Software keyboard "next" button
                    onEditingComplete: () {
                      print('Name editing complete');
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                canRequestFocus: false,
                // ↓ Focus widget handler, change color here
                onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                  if (hasFocus) {
                    print('Name GAINED focus');
                    setState(() {
                      bgColor = Colors.purple.withOpacity(.2);
                    });
                  }
                  else {
                    print('Name LOST focus');

                    setState(() {
                      bgColor = Colors.white;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password'
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think you can repeat this for each field you need colored.

Answer (score 2):

Hovering can be managed using the `hoverColor` property of `InputDecoration`:

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Hover TextField Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            hoverColor: Colors.indigo.shade200,
            hintText: 'Email',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every style property can be changed by `decoration` property, which requires an  `InputDecoration` object.

To handle the hover style, this object provides only the `hoverColor` property, which overwrite the `filledColor` when the mouse is hovering the widget. The `filled` property needs to be `true` for this to work.

```
InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            hoverColor: Colors.red,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
```

The problem is when you want to change others style properties like the border for example.

In that case you need to make your widget `Statefull` and add a state boolean like `isHover`.

Then you could wrap your widget inside `MouseRegion` and handle the hovering like in this example:

```
return MouseRegion(
    onEnter: (_)=>setState(()=>isHover = true),
    onExit: (_)=>setState(()=>isHover = false),
    child: YourWidget(),
);
```

Once `isHover` is available you can use wherever you want to change the UI according to the hover state.

Example with border:

```
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            hoverColor: Colors.red,
            border: isHover? OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 1.5,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ) : null,
            //By leaving null, the component will use the default value
          ),
        ),
```

I think the limitation is due to the fact that the `hover` behaviour is more web/desktop related. I hope flutter is going to implement better properties to handle this inside `InputDecoration`.